# c# xml multiple nested Arrays Deserializes

Tags: c#, xml

I tried this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/deserialize-xml-with-array-node

My question

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes>
<note>
  <to>
    <email>juan@gmail.com</email>
    <email>patrick@gmail.com</email>
    <email>Rose@gmail.com</email>
  </to>
  <from>Jose@hotmail.com</from>
  <heading>this is the email heading</heading>
</note>
</notes>
```

What do I have to do if I have multiple XmlArray?

Comment: can you share the sample, what do you mean by multiple xml array ?

Comment: *What do I have to do if I have multiple XmlArray?* - might you please [edit] your question to clarify what this statement means by sharing a [mcve] showing your code and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Your case is different from the link since you have an array at child of root Notes while link has array at grandchild of root.  See code below :

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notes));
            Notes notes = (Notes)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("notes")]
    public class Notes
    {
        [XmlElement("note")]
        public List<Note> note { get; set; }
    }
    public class Note
    {
        [XmlElement("to")]
        public To to { get; set; }
        public string from { get; set; }
        public string heading { get; set; }
    }
    public class To
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public List<string> email { get; set; }
    }


}
```